# How to get the average of the last X values?

Tags: mysql

If I have a table with two columns - value and time_stamp - how can I use SQL to get the average of the last X values?

One statement or several, it doesn't matter.

Maybe something like `SELECT value FROM table ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT x` ? Then in my program, I could get each value, total them and average them? That's my best guess so far as I am a SQL beginner.

I am aware that SQL can total / average, but I am unsure how to combine that with a request to apply it to the latest X values...

---

Note to anyone else seeking to do this: in addition to the accepted answer for the last X values, I also found by googling that it is easy to do for a time period, such as a minute or hour, by using something like `SELECT AVG(somefield) FROM sometable WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2003-08-10' AND '2003-08-26'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You  use the `AVG()` aggregate on the result of a subselect which does the initial `LIMIT`.  Just be sure to substitute the correct `LIMIT` value for `n` on the inner query.

```
SELECT AVG(a.value) AS the_average
FROM (SELECT value FROM tbl ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT n) a;
```

Comment: +1 (and the answer in 6 minutes, when I can award it). Thanks!

Comment: errm, I just noticed that final 'a' - what is it doing?

Comment: @Mawg subquery derived table must have an alias.  `a` is just a simple alias to fulfill that requirement -- without it the query won't compile.